# Counting the total observation per pixel

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, pixel

I generated a water mask using MNDWI. Now I would like to count the number of total observation and water detection per pixel as Global Surface Water dataset from JRC. I successfully counted the number of water detections, but for the number of total observation, I have no idea how they can count it. Can somebody give me some ideas or maybe help me dealing with this. Here is my code and link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a52f70aa759a0a11221c7a2add14098 .

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'black'}, 'Study Area',1);
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);

var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');

// Fmask classification values 
var non_mosaic = landsat8.filterBounds(roi).filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-6-1');

var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 3,3, 'Cloud_shadows').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 5,5, 'Cloud').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
  var c = clouds(image);
  image = image.updateMask(cs);
  return image.updateMask(c);
};

var clouds_free = non_mosaic.map(maskClouds);
var decision_tree = function(image){
  var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']);
  var evi = image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED)/(NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE+1)*2.5', {
      'BLUE': image.select('B2'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
      'NIR': image.select('B5'),
    });
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);
  var lswi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B6']);
  var water = evi.lt(0.1).and(mndwi.gt(evi).or(mndwi.gt(ndvi))).rename('water');
  //var vegetation = evi.gte(0.1).and (ndvi.gte(0.2)).and (lswi.gt(0)).rename('vegetation');
  return water.copyProperties(image);  
};

var result = clouds_free.map(decision_tree);
var freq = result.sum().divide(result.count());
print(result.count())
print(result.size())

var VisParamWar = {"bands":["water"],"min":0,"max":1};


var freq_mask = freq.updateMask(freq)
Map.addLayer(freq_mask.clip(roi),VisParamWar,'Water freq');

// Create a function to add a property representing the water frequency
var addFreqProperty = function(image) {
  var freq = image.select('water').divide(image.select('water').add(1));
  return image.addBands(freq.rename('water_frequency'));
};

// Map the function over the image collection and add the water frequency property
var resultWithFreq = result.map(addFreqProperty);

// Reduce the image collection to an image with the sum and count of water pixels per pixel
var waterCount = resultWithFreq.select(['water', 'water_frequency'])
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum().combine(ee.Reducer.count(), '', true));

// Rename the bands of the water count image
var waterCountRenamed = waterCount.select([1], ['water_count_total']);

// Add the water count image to the map
Map.addLayer(waterCountRenamed.clip(roi), {bands: 'water_count_total', min: 0, max: 600}, 'Water count');

// count the number of observation
```